# Unable to INSERT rows into MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a datebase lyrics with a table lyrics1, and with the code below I want to insert a row into lyrics1.

But when I go back to the mysql client and do `describe lyrics1`, it hasn't updated.

I get no error, it connects to the database fine. At least I don't get error saying it was unable to.

```
connectToDB();

ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {

            String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1(name, artist) values(?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, nameOfSong.getText()); // set input parameter 2
            statement.setString(2, artist.getText());   
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM lyrics1");
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (SQLException insertException) {
            displaySQLError(insertException);
        } 
        internalFrame.dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are never actual executing the `INSERT` statement, you just create it and never actual execute it. You are executing a `SELECT` but nothing actually sends the `INSERT` statement to the server.

You need to first call [`statement.executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) it will return the number of rows affected, most of the time you want to check that this is equal to 1 for INSERT and more than ZERO for UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: i execute it i just didn't show the rest of the code, essentially i called the method this code is under..

Comment: the code you have posted is fundamentally flawed, you need to post the entire thing or at least something that is correct, this isn't correct in any logical manner.